# How would I write this reportCandidates' function better?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting, collections

This is the input data in array named candidatesArray:

```
[ 
 {"name":"george","languages":["php","javascript","java"],"age":19,"graduate_date":1044064800000,"phone":"32-991-511"},
 {"name":"anna","languages":["java","javascript"],"age":23,"graduate_date":1391220000000,"phone":"32-991-512"},
 {"name":"hailee","languages":["regex","javascript","perl","go","java"],"age":31,"graduate_date":1296525600000,"phone":"32-991-513"}
]
```

I need to transform in this collection as a result of the function:

```
{candidates: [
    {name: "George", age: 19, phone: "32-991-511"},
    {name: "Hailee", age: 31, phone: "32-991-513"},
    {name: "Anna", age: 23, phone: "32-991-512"}
],
languages: [
    {lang:"javascript",count:1}, 
    {lang:"java", count:2}, 
    {lang:"php", count:2}, 
    {lang:"regex", count:1}
]}
```

The function repCandidates:

> `const reportCandidates = (candidatesArray) => {
>    return repObject}`

- I need to write it in javascript ES6
- I shouldn't use loops(for, while, repeat) but foreach is allowed and it could be better if I use "reduce" function
- The candidates should be return by their name, age and phone organized by their graduate_date.
- The languages should be returned with their counter in alphabetic order .

Visit https://codepen.io/rillervincci/pen/NEyMoV?editors=0010 to see my code, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to first `reduce` into the `candidates` subobject, while `push`ing the `langauges` of each to an array.

After iterating, sort the `candidates` and remove the `graduate_date` property from each candidate, then use `reduce` again to transform the `languages` array into one indexed by language, incrementing the `count` property each time:

```js
const input = [{
  "name": "george",
  "languages": ["php", "javascript", "java"],
  "age": 19,
  "graduate_date": 1044064800000,
  "phone": "32-991-511"
}, {
  "name": "anna",
  "languages": ["java", "javascript"],
  "age": 23,
  "graduate_date": 1391220000000,
  "phone": "32-991-512"
}, {
  "name": "hailee",
  "languages": ["regex", "javascript", "perl", "go", "java"],
  "age": 31,
  "graduate_date": 1296525600000,
  "phone": "32-991-513"
}];


const output = input.reduce((a, { languages, ...rest }) => {
  a.candidates.push(rest);
  a.languages.push(...languages);
  return a;
}, { candidates: [], languages: [] });

output.candidates.sort((a, b) => a.graduate_date - b.graduate_date);
output.candidates.forEach(candidate => delete candidate.graduate_date);

output.languages = Object.values(
  output.languages.reduce((a, lang) => {
    if (!a[lang]) a[lang] = { lang, count: 0 };
    a[lang].count++;
    return a;
  }, {})
);
output.languages.sort((a, b) => a.lang.localeCompare(b.lang));

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Wow that's amazing! 
I would never imagine do it like that. Very good... So how could I order the candidates by graduate date in desc and languages in alphabetic order

Comment: The `candidates` are already being sorted, see the `sort` function, to sort the languages by language, use `localeCompare` on their `lang` properties

Comment: Can I use this to make first letter of the names like lowercase?
name = name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1);
a.candidates.push({ name, age, phone });

Comment: You want to make each first character *uppercase*? Yep, that code looks like it would work, but note that you can use bracket notation instead of `charAt` for less syntax noise, eg `name[0].toUpperCase()`

Comment: Bracket notation? that's new to me

Comment: It worked succesfuly!!!
Thank you very much @CertainPerformance
I've learned all those codes with you today

Answer (score 1):

It's common practice to do everything in a `reduce()`, but sometimes it's easier to read if you break it up a bit. This creates a `counter` object as a helper to to track the language counts. `map()`s over the array to pull out the languages and personal info and then puts it all together:

```js
let arr = [ {"name":"george","languages":["php","javascript","java"],"age":19,"graduate_date":1044064800000,"phone":"32-991-511"},{"name":"anna","languages":["java","javascript"],"age":23,"graduate_date":1391220000000,"phone":"32-991-512"},{"name":"hailee","languages":["regex","javascript","perl","go","java"],"age":31,"graduate_date":1296525600000,"phone":"32-991-513"}]
 
let lang_counter = {
  // helper keeps counts of unique items
  counts:{},
  add(arr){
     arr.forEach(item => this.counts[item] = this.counts[item] ? this.counts[item] + 1 : 1)
  },
  toarray(){
    return Object.entries(this.counts).map(([key, val]) => ({[key]: val}))
  }
}

// iterate over object to create candidates 
let candidates = arr.map(row => {
  let {languages, ...person} = row
  lang_counter.add(languages)  // side effect
  return person
})

// put them together
console.log({candidates, languages:lang_counter.toarray()})
```

Comment: Yeaah That's nice bro. I've changed some things to make all names receive the first letter in uppercase and organize all languages in alphabetical order.
Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.reduce` and `Object.values` like below

```js
let arr = [{"name":"george","languages":["php","javascript","java"],"age":19,"graduate_date":1044064800000,"phone":"32-991-511"},{"name":"anna","languages":["java","javascript"],"age":23,"graduate_date":1391220000000,"phone":"32-991-512"},{"name":"hailee","languages":["regex","javascript","perl","go","java"],"age":31,"graduate_date":1296525600000,"phone":"32-991-513"}]


let res = arr.reduce((o, {name, age, phone, graduate_date, languages}) => {
    o.candidates.push({name, age, phone, graduate_date})
  
    languages.forEach(l => {
      o.languages[l] = o.languages[l] || { lang:l, count: 0 }
      o.languages[l].count++
    })
  
    return o
  }
 , { candidates: [], languages: {}})

res.candidates = res.candidates.sort((a,b) => a.graduate_date - b.graduate_date)
                               .map(({ graduate_date, ...rest }) => rest)

res.languages = Object.values(res.languages).sort((a,b) => a.lang.localeCompare(b.lang))
  
console.log(res)
```

Comment: It's very interesting
You've used map function to organize candidates
Woow Congratulations... Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to using more than just vanilla JavaScript, I can offer an intuitive solution.

```
import { TrueSet } from "@ut8pia/classifier/queue/TrueSet.js";
import { ORDER } from "@ut8pia/classifier/global.js";
import assert from "assert";

const 
    data = [ 
        {"name":"George","languages": "php","javascript","java"],"age":19,"graduate_date":1044064800000,"phone":"32-991-511"},
        {"name":"Anna","languages":["java","javascript"],"age":23,"graduate_date":1391220000000,"phone":"32-991-512"},
        {"name":"Hailee","languages":["regex","javascript","perl","go","java"],"age":31,"graduate_date":1296525600000,"phone":"32-991-513"}
    ],

    expected = {
        candidates: [
            {name: "George", age: 19, phone: "32-991-511"},
            {name: "Hailee", age: 31, phone: "32-991-513"},
            {name: "Anna", age: 23, phone: "32-991-512"}
        ],

        languages: [
            {lang: "go", count: 1},
            {lang: "java", count: 3}, 
            {lang: "javascript", count: 3}, 
            {lang: "perl", count: 1}, 
            {lang: "php", count: 1}, 
            {lang: "regex", count: 1}
        ]
    };
```

To define your `report(data)` function, all you need are  `representation` functions and TrueSets. Please, refer to the [@ut8pia/classifier](https://github.com/ut8pia/classifier) library's for an explanation.

Candidates are represented by their graduation dates, while languages are self-represented. The `TrueSet` consistently tallies the occurrence frequency of each item and offers the method `n(item)` to retrieve them. Adding your data to the TrueSets is all that's required.

```
function report(data) {

    const
        candidates = TrueSet.of(candidate => candidate.graduate_date, ORDER.ASCENDING, ORDER.INSERTION)
            .letAll(data),
        languages = new TrueSet(language => language)
            .letAll(data
                    .map(candidate => candidate.languages)
                        .flat());
    return {
        candidates: candidates 
            .toArray()
                .map(candidate => ({name: candidate.name, age: candidate.age, phone: candidate.phone})),

        languages: languages
            .toArray()
                .map(language => ({lang: language, count: languages.n(language)}))
    }
}
```

You can validate the result by:

```
const got = report(data);

assert.deepEqual(got, expected);
```